# $Ax = kx$ for complex scalar $k$ and complex vector $x$, and symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Prove that if $Ax = kx$ for some non-zero, possibly complex valued scalar $k$ and non-zero complex valued vector $x$, and real symmetric $n$x$n$ matrix $A$, then $k$ must be real valued.

A hint was given saying to consider the complex conjugates. I'm unsure how to go about this proof. I tried splitting $k$ and $x$ into complex form, $a + bi$, and $c + di$ respectively (note that c and d are $n$x$1$ column vectors and a and b are real valued scalars). So $Ax =  Ac + Adi = ac - bd + adi + bci$. We want to prove that $b = 0$. So it may be helpful to isolate that term better. $Ax = a(c + di) + b(ci - d)$. However, I don't know where to go from here or where the complex conjugate becomes relevant, nor how the fact that A is symmetric is useful. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: While we work with complex numbers here, I assume $A$ is real?

Comment: On which field is $A$ defined ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, A is a real nxn matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that $A$ is a real matrix; denote by $H$ the conjugate transpose: then $A^H=A^T=A$. Then
$$
k(x^Hx)=x^H(kx)=x^HAx=x^HA^Hx=(Ax)^Hx=(kx)^Hx=\bar{k}(x^Hx)
$$
Since $x\ne0$, also $x^Hx\ne0$ and so $k=\bar{k}$.

Note that the proof just requires that $A=A^H$, so it can even have complex coefficients (it's called Hermitian, in this case).

---

Without the conjugate transpose, let $\bar{x}$ be the vector you get from $x$ by conjugating all entries. Then do the same:
$$
k(\bar{x}^Tx)=\bar{x}^T(kx)=\bar{x}^TAx=\bar{x}^TA^Tx=
(A\bar{x})^Tx=(\overline{Ax})^Tx=(\bar{k}\bar{x})^Tx=\bar{k}(\bar{x}^Tx)
$$

Comment: but in the case of complex $A$, it must be hermitian instead of symmetric, of course

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen “The proof requires $A=A^H$”.

Comment: Can this be done without the conjugate transpose? We have not learned anything like that in my class, and my teacher simply won't accept us using material we haven't learned to prove something.

Comment: @infinitylord Not really. I added a proof without the conjugate transpose. You can try rewriting it in terms of real and imaginary parts. But the multiplication by $\bar{x}$ is needed some way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not true in general. Take $A$ to be the following :
$$
A=\left[\begin{matrix}
1&i\\
i&1
\end{matrix}\right].
$$
then $k=1+i$ and $x=[1, 1]^T$ stasify $Ax=kx$.

Now if $A$ is Hermitian then this is true and the proof is as follows. Take  $x^*Ax$, we can see $x^*Ax=(Ax)^*x=k^*x^*x$ and $x^*Ax=x^*kx=kx^*x$ and therefore $k=k^*$ which means that $k$ is real. ($x^*$ is the conjugate transpose.) If $A$ is real matrix then hermitian boils down to symmetric.